# How to dereference a pointer address?

Tags: c++, pointers

I am given a function call with an "&" before the variable parameters. Not sure how to dereference them when building out the actual function.

```
int state_1 = 1;
int input_1 = digitalRead(PIN_1);
int output_1;

edge_detect(input_1,&state_1,&output_1);


void edge_detect(int input, int* button_state, int* output) {
    int theOutput = *output
    int bState = *button_state;
    if (bState == 1 && input == 0){
       theOutput = 1;
       bState = 0;
    }
    else if (bState == 0 && input == 1){
       theOutput = -1;
       bState = 1;
    }
    else{
       theOutput = 0;
    }
}
```

When I print to serial, the final result is what appears to be a 5 digit address for output_1. I expect output_1 to be either a 1 or a 0.

Comment: not clear what is the problem. You are derferencing the pointers. Do you get unexpected output? Then what do you expect? What do you get?

Comment: You are dereferencing output point here `int theOutput = *output`

Comment: its not dererencing that is the problem in your code, but the problem is that there are parameters that are supposed to be out-parameters but you dont write anything to them

Comment: _@immiller_ Post a [mcve] that reproduces your problem as required here please.

Comment: is this really c++ ? If yes, do not use pointers but references, or even better return the value from the function instead of using out-parameters

Comment: @user463035818 arduino library for c++, yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### You never modify `output_1`!

This means that whatever junk value it starts with when you do `int output_1;` will be what you print. This is undefined behavior.

It looks like you mean to change it in `edge_detect()` since you're passing a pointer to it, but you only modify a copy of the integer it was storing. To modify the value of `output_1` itself, either change `theOutput` to be a reference:

```
int &theOutput = *output
```

or get rid of `theOutput` altogether:

```
//...
else if (bState == 0 && input == 1){
   *output = -1;
   bState = 1;
}
else{
   *output = 0;
}
```

Comment: @immiller it happens. If you test each function as you write it, you would've caught that `edge_detect()` wasn't changing `output_1` properly. Incremental programming will save you hours in the long run!

Answer (score 0):

> How to dereference a pointer address?

You can indirect through a pointer (i.e. dereference) using the indirection operator which is the unary operator `*`. Like this:

```
int o;         // object
int *ptr = &o; // pointer to the object
*ptr = 10;     // the pointer is indirected, and o is assigned
```

---

P.S. Unless `output_1` has static storage, it will have an indeterminate value. When its address is passed to `edge_detect`, the indeterminate value is accessed on the line:

> ```
> int theOutput = *output
> ```

As a consequence, the behaviour of the program would be undefined. This is not a problem if `output_1` has static storage because in that case it is zero initialised.